# Enabling the "Use Windows XP Style DPI scaling" option in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display

On Windows 7, if you go to Display > Set Custom text size (DPI), the "Use Windows XP Style DPI scaling" option is disabled (greyed out).

What do I need to do to enable this option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will find that "XP style DPI scaling" is *only* relevant if you have the **aero interface** active.

I've just confirmed on my machine - if I disable aero, the option becomes unavailable and when I then reactivate aero this reactivates the option.

If the aero interface is deactive you will effectively be using XP style scaling *anyway* because you are using the XP style interface.